# How to add an exception to account for invalid user input? User should input a name and I need to throw an exception if input is not a name

Tags: java, validation, exception, input, error-handling

Brand new to Java, just started last Friday after wrapping up Javascript training. I have an exercise that's asking for the following (I've **bolded** everything I haven't yet completed):

- Provide information about students in a class
- Prompt the user to ask about a particular student
- Give proper responses according to user-submitted information
- Ask if user would like to learn about another student
- **Account for invalid user input with exceptions**
- **Try to incorporate IndexOutOfBoundsException and
  IllegalArgumentException**
- Make it easy for the user - tell them what information is available
- Use parallel arrays to hold the student data

I've scoured StackOverflow for answers, and found a lot of helpful stuff, but it all seems to relate to integers and not strings...though maybe it's just my dumb monkey brain.

I don't believe the "Try to incorporate IndexOutOfBoundsException and
IllegalArgumentException" instruction is a requirement, so don't feel like you have to include those.

Any helpful tips or direction would me much appreciated...and please don't laugh at my code, although constructive criticism is much obliged.

Without further ado:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students {
    private static String[] students = {"John", "Ben", "Lisa", "Stewart", "Cora"};
    private static int[] grades = {79, 86, 90, 89, 99};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean userChoice = true;
        String userInput;
        String choice;

        while(userChoice) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a Student's name to get their grade: ");

            userInput = kb.nextLine();
            
            getGrades(userInput);

            System.out.println("Continue? (y/n)");

            choice = kb.nextLine();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                userChoice = false;
            }
        }
        kb.close();
    }

    private static void getGrades(String userInput) {
        int length = students.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(userInput.equals(students[i])) {
                System.out.println(userInput + "'s " + "grade is: " + grades[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of my output:

> [John, Ben, Lisa, Stewart, Cora]
>
> Please enter a Student's name to get their grade:
>
> *Ben*
>
> Ben's grade is: 86
>
> Continue? (y/n)
>
> *y*
>
> Please enter a Student's name to get their grade:
>
> *Lisa*
>
> Lisa's grade is: 90
>
> Continue? (y/n)
>
> *n*
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

By the way, although I just signed up today for help with this problem, this community has been a godsend to me while learning Javascript so this a formal thank you to all you glorious bastards!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own :P

Ended up creating a list from my students array and using the contains method to compare user input to my list of students, and if input doesn't match a student in the array then it throws an exception and prints "Not a valid student's name" and asks if you want to input another name.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students {
    private static String[] students = {"John", "Ben", "Lisa", "Stewart", "Cora"};
    private static int[] grades = {79, 86, 90, 89, 99};
    private static String[] behavior = {"aggressive", "distractable", "attentive", "disruptive", "angelic"};
    private static List myList = Arrays.asList(students);


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean userChoice = true;
        String userInput;
        String choice;

        while(userChoice) {

            System.out.println(myList);

            System.out.println("Please enter a student's name (case-sensitive) to get their progress report: ");

            userInput = kb.nextLine();

            try {
                if (myList.contains(userInput)) {
                    getGrades(userInput);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid student's name");
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another student's name? (y/n)");

            choice = kb.nextLine();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                userChoice = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void getGrades(String userInput) {
        for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            if(userInput.equals(students[i])) {
                System.out.println(userInput + "'s " + "grade is " + grades[i] + " and they are " + behavior[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```